# What is the tangent space of a two-dimensional domain?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

Consider a map $f:M\to N$, and let $p\in M$. We can define the differential of $f$ at point $p$ as a map from $T_pM$ to $T_{f(p)} N$, and this map is linear. And because of that, we can come up with a matrix representation for this thing.

So far that is my understanding of what a differential is, and I was trying to confirm that on simple cases. First I was working on a function from $U\subset R^2$ to $V\subset R^2$, but I'm not sure what is the tangent space of domain in this case. Is it just the plane itself? But then what about a function $g:R\to R$? What is the tangent space of an interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tangent spaces go with points, tangent bundles go with domains. The tangent space of a point in a domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is indeed a copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $f:U\to V$, you have met its differential $df$ before as the Jacobian matrix of $f$.

Likewise, the tangent space of a point in $\mathbb{R}$ is again another copy of $\mathbb{R}$. If $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, then its derivative $g'$ maps $T_x\mathbb{R}\to T_{g(x)}\mathbb{R}$ by $v\mapsto g'(x)v.$

Comment: I haven't learned about what a tangent bundle is, but I'll look it up later. Thanks!